# Wen scrapping price

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrap the total price from link [holidays](https://r.pl/mozaika-polnocy/zakwaterowanie-mrg?data=20230901&miastoWyjazdu=katowice&wyzywienie=2-posilki&wiek=1993-03-11&wiek=1993-03-11&liczbaPokoi=1&czyCenaZaWszystkich=0&iataWyjazdu=WAW&dlugoscPobytu=15&hotelNaPrzedluzenie=riu-tikida-palace-taghazout)

I 've tried to use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) from [python](/questions/tagged/python) to do this but it failed, next i have tried to use [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71280231/beautiful-soup-findall-doesnt-find-value] solution but it failed too.

Is it possible to do this by any other methods ?

Comment: Did you try selenium.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Also provide a [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The price and other info is loaded with Javascript from different URL (You should see this URL in Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab):

```
import json
import requests

api_url = 'https://r.pl/api/v4.1/wyszukiwarka/wyszukaj-kalkulator'

payload = {
    "CzyAvg": True,
    "DatyUrodzenia": [
        "1993-03-12",
        "1993-03-12"
    ],
    "Dlugosc": 15,
    "HotelNaPrzedluzenieUrl": "riu-tikida-palace-taghazout",
    "HotelUrl": "zakwaterowanie-mrg",
    "Iata": "WAW",
    "LiczbaPokoi": 1,
    "ProduktUrl": "mozaika-polnocy",
    "TerminWyjazdu": "2023-09-01"
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

#to print all data uncomment next line:
#print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data['Wybrany']['Cena'])
```

Prints:

```
8253
```